# Image processing with .HPG files

Tags: image-processing, python, computer-vision

I have files with extension .hpg and I want to perform image processing on those file as they are hp plotter file.

I tried googling but no luck there.

hence hope someone can help me tackle this with some clue.

Comment: Can you print the first 50 lines of that file? If it contains character pairs such as PD, DC, IP followed by numbers, then these files contain [G-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code). G-code tells the plotter what to do (pick up a 0.5 pen, draw a line, lift the pen, move a bit south, draw another line, etc). This means that you first have to build a program that parses the file, builds the 2D image AND THEN process it. Not too difficult, if one does not already exist.

Comment: @A_A it is having a G-code and I did find out a python library that helped parse code into pdf. now I am trying to extract text to do data processing on it. Thanks

Comment: Does your file open in [GRBL-Plotter](https://github.com/svenhb/GRBL-Plotter)?

Comment: @jojek this one is really helpful, I still am struggling it to process it in python.